# 'It's she who' vs 'It's hers who'

Tags: pronouns, relative-pronouns, possessives

1. It's she who had to leave her family.
2. It's hers who had to leave her family.

What's difference in between? Are they grammatically correct?
I'm not sure about the use possesive pronouns in the second sentence.

Answer (score 0):

It is she who had to leave her family is technically correct.

Hers is possessive so does not make sense within the sentence.

It is also simpler to say "she had to leave her family". While your sentence is not wrong, it is a very long winded way of saying it the same thing.

Comment: Can I use objective forms of pronouns like me, her etc. rather than she, I, they?